# Youtube Player API Ended state never fired

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

Hi so i have implemented the Youtube Player API and based on the event i am doing certain things, it is working perfectly for when the video is playing or when it is paused however when the video is ended the ended event is never called, instead it recalls the paused event. I get the url for the video using a get from the url bar, this is working perfectly.

```
<script>
function get(name){
    if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}

//Load player api asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: get('url'),
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(evt) {
   // evt.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        $.ajax({ url:'insertToDBFromVid.php',
            data: {action : 'playing' },
            type: 'post',
            done: function(result){
                alert(result);
                console.log("Success, Playing");
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert(result)
                console.log("Error in Playing");
            }});

    }
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){
        //done=true;
        //console.log("Ended called!");
        $.ajax({ url:'insertToDBFromVid.php',
            data: {action : 'ended' },
            type: 'post',
            done: function(result){
                alert(result);
                console.log("Success, Ended");
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert(result)
                console.log("Error in Ended");
            }});
    }       
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        $.ajax({ url:'insertToDBFromVid.php',
            data: {action : 'paused' },
            type: 'post',
            done: function(result){
                alert(result);
                console.log("Success, Paused");
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert(result)
                console.log("Error in Paused");
            }});
    }

}
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
```

If anyone can shine a light onto why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: 2021 and I'm facing the exact same problem: videos that reach the "end" do not trigger the "ENDED" state. In fact, I can see in the player that there is 1 second left of play, but the video has simply stopped. No idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things I scream at YouTube's API, and your issue you are experiencing is one of them :)

From YouTube API Docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls

> Important: Unlike the pauseVideo function, which leaves the player in the paused (2) state, the stopVideo function could put the player into any not-playing state, including ended (0), paused (2), video cued (5) or unstarted (-1).

So if you use `player.stopVideo()`, the state may change into any state listed in the quote.

The work-a-round is to not use `stopVideo()` but instead use:

```
player.seekTo( player.getDuration(), true );
player.playVideo(); //Can be ommitted if video is already playing
```

The YouTube player seems to always change the state to `ENDED` if the player naturally ends. So the above workaround seeks the video to the end of the video, then plays the video so that the video will naturally end.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't quite understand what you mean, I am actually never setting the video to end rather waiting for the video to end naturally like you say in the hope that it sets the player state to ENDED, however this never happens. Can you supply a sample code to explain better what you mean?

Comment: So you are not using `stopVideo()`?